# can "as described below" be used instead of as follows?

Tags: phrase-usage

I sometimes use "as follows" as follows:

> The system operates **as follows.** First, it receives data. Then, it
>   processes the data. ...

That is, I sometimes uses "as follows" with a period not colon when a long explanation is needed after "as follows". But, as far as I know,  using "as follows" with a period is incorrect, so I am looking for alternative expressions that can be used with a period. Is it correct to replace "as follows" with "as described below" as follows?:

> The system operates **as described below.** First, it receives data. Then, it
>   processes the data. ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system operates as described below. First, it receives data. Then, it processes the data could be substituted with:

The system operates in the following manner (or way): first, it receives data and then it processes the data